# Is it possible to earn achievements in Steam for Rainbow Six Vegas 2? If so, how do I set up Steam to earn achievements?

Tags: steam, rainbow-six-vegas-2

Steam support representatives told me that I cannot register the game though Steam, and it says so in their FAQ as well. (I think it is because RSV2 keys only have 19 characters, and typical Steam keys have 20 or 25 characters. I think this is why it is incompatible.) I had bought it through Direct2Drive.

However, I would like to earn Steam achievements in Rainbow Six Vegas 2. I am able to get the Steam overlay by choosing "add a non-steam game" (as the Steam support instructed me to do). I am not sure though if it is possible to earn achievements; and if it is possible, I need to know how to do it.

In short, is it possible to earn Steam achievements in Rainbow Six Vegas 2? If so, how do I set up Rainbow Six Vegas 2 to earn achievements?

Comment: This is basically the same question as your [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49749/how-can-i-sync-achievements-for-unreal-tournament-2004-and-quake-live-with-my-s) on the subject of non-Steam games and achievements.  You might want to make that one a bit more generic, as the answer applies to both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

You cannot get Achievements for Games that did not register them on Steam or insert any achievements. Doing so requires the developer of the game having access to the Steamworks API and adding their achievements to the Steam Community.

Link: https://partner.steamgames.com/